# SSIS - #na in ms sql while importing excel data

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have build a SSIS package where all .xlsb files are pulled from a folder and updated to a temp file. I had built the package with the existing excel files I had, it worked fine and now I have received a new data set in xlsb only but I see few columns getting update as #NA. Also I get error

Also with the new data I got error saying

> VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA

so I turned the data validation to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA` error is probably because you changed something in your schema. just double click on your inputs/outputs, click OK and it should resolve itself.

Have you checked what columns/fields are getting updates as #NA? Most likely it are fields that are empty in the xlsb and could be replaced in your SSIS package with null by using a derived column.

Comment: I would get new excel files every time and I will copy these data and paste it as values in a new excel file and save it in the folder path. Also my connection string is a variable so every time if I have to connect to the new file it wouldn't be a feasible solution. And no these are not empty fields. Data has been pulled to those columns through vlookup and I converted them to values as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel Connection manager, try below things:

1. In source task, test with both the options (true/false) of 'Validate external Metadata'
2. If your excel column contains combined values of characters, numbers and alphanumeric, add **IMEX=1** to the extended properties of excel connection manager.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3d-XIYuB7k